# How can be made a colormap in matplotlib from gnuplot commands?

Tags: matplotlib, gnuplot, colormap

I want to use the gnuplot color map in Python. The attached picture is generated in gnuplot using the surface plot command. But I don't know much about gnuplot and its colormaps.

[image]

How can I make a colormap in matplotlib similar to this gnuplot colormap?
Gnuplot commands for shown picture are as follows. But it is not possible to provide the files used in the code.

```
set palette rgb 32,3,36 negative

set style line 1 lc rgb "blue" pt 6 ps 0.6
set style line 2 lc rgb "blue" pt 6 ps 0.5
set style line 3 lt 2 lc rgb "red"
set style line 4 lc rgb "black" lw 0.5
set style line 5 lc rgb "blue" pt 7 ps 0.2
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The commands that I given are custom colormaps. I am using the codes written by others. There is no harm in sharing commands.

Comment: Unfortunately, I couldn't add the code to comment because it is little bir long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The colormap is defined in Gnuplot as `set palette rgb 32,3,36 negative`, so it's a colormap in which (see the output of `show palette rgbformulae`)

- the red channel goes with linear segments from (0, 0) to (0.25, 1) to (0.42, 1) to (0.92, 0) to (1,1),
- the green channel goes from (0, 0) to (1,1) and eventually
- the blue channel goes from (0, 0) to (0.5, 0) to (1, 1).

[image]

Matplotlib provides [`LinearSegmentedColormap`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.html#matplotlib-colors-linearsegmentedcolormap) to deal with this type of colormap definition, below you will find how to define a colormap matching the one defined in Gnuplot

```
In [62]: %reset -fs
    ...: import numpy as np
    ...: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    ...: from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap
    ...: 
    ...: cdata = {'red':[[0, 0, 0], [0.25, 1, 1], [0.42, 1, 1], [0.92, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1]],
    ...:          'green':[[0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1]],
    ...:          'blue':[[0,0,0], [0.5,0,0], [1,1,1]]}
    ...: gnuplot_cm = LinearSegmentedColormap('test', cdata)
    ...: 
    ...: np.random.seed(1)
    ...: data = np.random.randn(30, 30)
    ...: fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(4, 3), constrained_layout=True)
    ...: cmesh = ax.pcolormesh(data, cmap=gnuplot_cm, vmin=-2, vmax=2)
    ...: fig.colorbar(cmesh, ax=ax)
    ...: plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Your answer is marvelous, no other words are needed, thank you so much @gbofii. Also you gave us a lecture as well. Thanks a million again.

Comment: I look at the output of the command `show palette rgbformulae`, but it was little bir complex, I couldn't find the RGB numbers as you defined. How can I obtain these RGB limits 0.25, 0.42 and 0.92 in red channels and others?

Comment: The output of red channel is like that ` 0: 0              
 3: x              
 6: x^4            
 9: sin(90x)       
12: (2x-1)^2       
15: sin(360x)      
18: |cos(360x)|    
21: 3x             
24: |3x-1|         
27: (3x-2)/2       
30: x/0.32-0.78125 
33: |2*x - 0.5|    
36: 2*x - 1`

Comment: @Bluerose when you say `set palette rgb 32,3,36` oit means "use formula no. 32 for the red channel, formula no.3 for the green channel and formula no. 36 for the blue channel. The simplest one is no. 3 `x` this means that green follows a ramp from 0 to 1, because `x` is intended to go from 0 to 1 too, to understand the other formulas, plot the different parts and keep the result bounded by 0 and 1.

Comment: In my case these parameters are `32: 4x;1;-2x+1.84;x/0.08-11.5 for R, 3: x for G and  36: 2*x - 1 for B` arent't they?

Comment: @Bluerose Formula no. 32, for red, is `4x;1;-2x+1.84;x/0.08-11.5`, you start from (0,0), use `4x` and at point (0.25,1) you reach the top, so you use the next formula, a constant `1`, until the next function `-2x+1,84` breaks in at (0,42, 1), then you go down using `-2x+1,84` until you hit (0.92, 0), eventually the last function `x/0.08-11.5` goes from (0.92,0) to (1.1)